# find & formulate the next saturday in a row - excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

i need to write a formulate where it can dynamically change accordingly when the month changes.

week 1 (cell B16) calculates the row 4 till the first saturday of the month, week 2 (cell C16) calculates the row 4 from the next monday (after first sunday) till the second saturday, week 3 (cell D16) calculates the row 4 from the second monday of the month (after second sunday) till the third saturday and week 4 (cell E16) calculates the row 4 from the third monday of the month (after third sunday) till the fourth saturday, and the week 5 (cell F16) calculates the row 4 from the fourth monday of the month (after fourth sunday) till the fifth saturday if any.

i know i need to use **index**, **match**, **row** etc but i just couldn't formulate it.

i need to formulate the arrays in the formula so we can have dynamic arrays which changes according to the month and days without changing the columns... B4:G4 , B$3:G$3 etc...

Please help.

Thank you...

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJgjG57MFeTfdatgtn?e=Mg7rnZ)

Comment: @BigBen i tried actually.  but edited the question one more time, i hope i am more clear now. thanks

Comment: As per your explanation, every week goes from Monday till Saturday, so Sundays are not added, however, Sunday 7/21/2019 has a value of 10 in row 4. Please clarify. Would please show the expected values for each week.

Comment: @EEM even though sundays have a value, we omit that values... thank you for your interest... expected values are shown on the row 16... i only need to formulate the arrays in the formula so we can have dynamic arrays which changes according to the month... B4:G4 , $B$3:$G$3 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data is located at `B1:AF4` enter these formulas in the cells of your preference:

week 1:

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,    
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( $B$2, WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) = 1 ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 7, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )
```

week 2:

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,    
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 9, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 14, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )
```

week 3:

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,    
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 16, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 21, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )
```

week 4:

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,    
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 23, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 28, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )
```

week 5:

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,    
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 30, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 35, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )
```

week 6 (*):

```
= SUMIFS( $B$4:$AF$4,
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 37, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ),    
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( EOMONTH( $B$2, 0 ), -( WEEKDAY( EOMONTH( $B$2, 0 ), 1 ) = 1 ) ) )
```

[image]

[image]

(*) Note that as per your definition of a week the period of August-2020 will have six weeks.

Also, suggest to change the formula in `C2:AF2` with this one:

```
= IFERROR( IF( B2= EOMONTH( B2, 0 ), "", 1 + B2 ), "" )
```

Comment: the first week caculation is ok, but the rest does not equal to manual calculation. can you please check again ? 

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJoHKpP4qSLVA_DqSN?e=5kDBdE

Comment: =SUMIFS( $B4:$AF4,
$B$2:$AF$2, ">=" & SUM( 7,$B$2, WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) = 1 ),
$B$2:$AF$2, "<=" & SUM( 14, $B$2, -WEEKDAY( $B$2, 1 ) ) )


the second part of the formula shall be 7 instead of 9 ;)

Comment: @UmutK, I'm afraid you are not using the formulas correctly, at least in the revised sample file you posted. Please note that the formulas 2 to 5 are different to the formula 1. You just entered the formula for week 1 and copied to the week 2 to 5 and only changed the numbers after `SUM(` without realizing that in the formulas week 2 to 5 the first part is `-WEEKDAY` instead of `WEEKDAY`. Please use each of the formulas as stated in the answer, they were tested and are working correctly. Do not take shortcuts.

Comment: even with or without the minus in the weeks 2-5 , it works normally when you change the numbers in the first *sum (*  see the file... https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJoHKpP4qSLVA_DqSN?e=FQcFnS

Comment: would you please just use the formulas provided, I have updated the formulas in your file, have a look at it.

Comment: if you check the sums, they dont match, for example when you manually calculate (cell I10) it is 55 but with your formula (cell I17), it is 37... please check the cells in red... with my revision to your formulas, it sums exactly as targeted...

Comment: I entered the correct formulas at `H21:L23`, what you entered at `I17:L19` are not the formulas provided in the answer. Would you please have a look at them before continuing with this erroneous claim.